# Getting list of facebook page GEM koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I have a helper. Gets a list of the facebook fanpage. A few days ago to work, suddenly stopped. I stop after taking one fanpage. I get this error:

```
type: OAuthException, code: 100, message: (#100) Invalid Connection [HTTP 400]
```

This is my helper

```
  def self.download_fanpages(user_id)

#API Facebook
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(Client.find(user_id).access_token.to_s) 

#download list of fanpage
for facebook_page in @graph.get_object("me/accounts/page")
  @graphs = Koala::Facebook::API.new(facebook_page["access_token"]) 
  @url = @graphs.get_object("me") 
  if @url['link'].index("facebook")    
    if !Fanpage.find_by_uid_and_user(facebook_page["id"],user_id)
      @fb = Fanpage.new
      @fb.user = user_id
    else
      @fb = Fanpage.find_by_uid(facebook_page["id"])
    end
    @fb.name = facebook_page["name"]
    @fb.access_token = facebook_page["access_token"]
    @fb.uid = facebook_page["id"]
    @fb.url = @url['link']

    #install or not install
    if @graphs.get_object("me/tabs/"+APP_ID.to_s).count > 0
      @fb.install = 1
    else
      @fb.install = 0
    end
    @fb.save
  end
end
end
```

Does anyone else have a similar problem. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your access token expired.  They don't last very long.  I'm guessing you saved it in your database a couple days ago, and it worked for a while but then expired.  You need to fetch a new access token pretty much every session, and update it in your database.